# sql query condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

l've a table named gst that contain

```
CREATE TABLE gst (
    gst_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    month VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    price INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO gst 
(gst_id,    month, price)
  VALUES
(     7, February,   3),
(    16,  January,   5)
(    17,    April,   7),
(    18,    March,   2),
```

I want to display a result in the order of month (ie january, february, march.........):

```
16             January         5
 7             February           3
18             March             2
17             April             7
```

How can I write the sql query?

Comment: This is why you should store the month numbers instead of the month names in your database :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%M') as month FROM table ORDER BY month
```

Try this link also...

[Date-Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: `select DATE_FORMAT('January', '%M');` --- try to perform this at first. `DATE_FORMAT` accepts `date` or `datetime` as a parameter, not a month name.

Answer (score 2):

```
... ORDER BY CASE `month`
        WHEN 'January' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Febduary' THEN 2
        ...
     END
```

Or

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`month`, 'January,February,March,...')
```

Or

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`month`, 'January', 'February', ...)
```